# for loop is running two times only

Tags: c#, sql-server

After 12 Hours of searching i am unable to solve my problem.

In SQL I made 2 procedure one for insert and 2nd one would check the database if item already exists it will update & Insert in it on Items Log..

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Purchase_Order WHERE Item_Name = '" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value + "' and Seller_Name = '" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + "' and Company_Name = '" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + "' ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet da = new DataSet();
        ds.Fill(da);
        int j = da.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (j > 0)
        {
            update(dgv, Date_of_Purchase, Discount, Paid_Amount, lbl_Remaining, lbl_Subtotal, lbl_Total);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Purchase_Order_History", con);
            sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invoice_no", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_of_Purchase", Date_of_Purchase.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Name", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seller_Name", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_Name", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit_Price", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", Discount.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid_Amount", Paid_Amount.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remaining", lbl_Remaining.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub_Total", lbl_Subtotal.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", lbl_Total.Text);

            sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    SuccessBox sb = new SuccessBox();
    sb.ShowDialog();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

This Code is checking the item if already exist then it will update the code..
Update Code is here...

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Update_Insert", con);
        sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invoice_no", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_of_Purchase", Date_of_Purchase.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Name", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seller_Name", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_Name", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit_Price", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", Discount.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid_Amount", Paid_Amount.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remaining", lbl_Remaining.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub_Total", lbl_Subtotal.Text);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", lbl_Total.Text);

        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        i++;
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Actually my problem is when I enter the same item that already exist in database it will update it but if I add new items with it it will add only 1 new item after that it goes to throw.

Any solution would be helpful.

My Stored Procedure Purchase_Order_history:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Purchase_Order_History]
(
@Invoice_no int,
@Date_of_Purchase date,
@Item_Name nvarchar(100),
@Seller_Name nvarchar(100),
@Company_Name nvarchar(100),
@Quantity int,
@Unit_Price int,
@Total_Price int,
@Discount int,
@Paid_Amount int,
@Remaining int,
@Sub_Total int,
@Total int,
@Selling_Price int = null
)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Purchase_Order(Invoice_no, Date_of_Purchase, Item_Name, 
Seller_Name, Company_Name, Quantity, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Discount, 
Paid_Amount, Remaining, Sub_Total, Total) 
VALUES(@Invoice_no, @Date_of_Purchase,@Item_Name, @Seller_Name, 
@Company_Name, @Quantity,@Unit_Price, @Total_Price, @Discount, @Paid_Amount, 
@Remaining, @Sub_Total, @Total);

INSERT INTO Purchase_Order_Log(Invoice_no, Date_of_Purchase, Item_Name, 
Seller_Name, Company_Name, Quantity, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Discount, 
Paid_Amount, Remaining, Sub_Total, Total) 
VALUES(@Invoice_no, @Date_of_Purchase,@Item_Name, @Seller_Name, 
@Company_Name, @Quantity,@Unit_Price, @Total_Price, @Discount, @Paid_Amount, 
@Remaining, @Sub_Total, @Total);

INSERT INTO Items(Date_of_Purchase, Item_Name, Seller_Name, Company_Name, 
Available_Stock, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Selling_Price) 
VALUES(@Date_of_Purchase,@Item_Name, @Seller_Name, @Company_Name, 
@Quantity,@Unit_Price, @Total_Price, @Selling_Price);


END
```

2nd Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Insert]
(
@Invoice_no int,
@Date_of_Purchase date,
@Item_Name nvarchar(100),
@Seller_Name nvarchar(100),
@Company_Name nvarchar(100),
@Quantity int,
@Unit_Price int,
@Total_Price int,
@Discount int,
@Paid_Amount int,
@Remaining int,
@Sub_Total int,
@Total int
)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Purchase_Order_Log(Invoice_no, Date_of_Purchase, Item_Name, 
Seller_Name, Company_Name, Quantity, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Discount, 
Paid_Amount, Remaining, Sub_Total, Total) 
VALUES(@Invoice_no, @Date_of_Purchase,@Item_Name, @Seller_Name, 
@Company_Name, @Quantity,@Unit_Price, @Total_Price, @Discount, @Paid_Amount, 
@Remaining, @Sub_Total, @Total);

UPDATE Purchase_Order SET Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity, Unit_Price = 
@Unit_Price, Total_Price = Total_Price + @Total_Price Where Item_Name = 
@Item_Name AND Company_Name = @Company_Name AND Seller_Name = @Seller_Name

UPDATE Items SET Available_Stock = Available_Stock + @Quantity, Unit_Price = 
@Unit_Price, Total_Price = Total_Price + @Total_Price Where Item_Name = 
@Item_Name AND Company_Name = @Company_Name AND Seller_Name = @Seller_Name

END
```

After Removing -1 from update for loop and i add command into for loop but its printing new item 2 times??

Comment: First, do not code a catch block that does nothing other than re-throw the exception. Second, what is the exception message?

Comment: What is in your Stored Procedure?

Comment: Insert_Update has too many arguments

Comment: Call `sc.Parameters.Clear();` before you add them.

Comment: Either clear your parameters or simply don't reuse your command - put the creation of the command inside your for-loop, like you do in the first bit of code. And indeed, your try-catch is useless in the code you show...

Comment: Your `con` should really be inside a using statement, if it is not if a exception happens the connection to the server will not be closed.

Comment: @oerkelens i add my command inside the for loop its updating the existing item very well but when i adding new item with existing item it's adding duplicate rows of new item?

Comment: I updated my stored_procedure please have a look at it

Comment: OT it is great that you use parameters, but ... https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Is the `i++;` at the end of the for-loop intentional? The for-loop is already increasing `i`.

Comment: Can you check your  dgv.Rows object. If is there duplicate entries,this could your main problem.

Comment: There is no duplicate entries @A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of two stored procedure you can user

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_Name WHERE condition) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO table_Name (id,name) 
VALUES 
(@id, @name)
END
ELSE 
UPDATE table_Name SET id = @id, name = @name 
WHERE condition
```

I am putting this sample structure because your query is very long. converted sample query into your query and try to execute it will help to you

Comment: if my answer is correct then please accept so if others have the same problem then they can just use it. or if wrong then you can post the answer

Comment: Yes Your Answer Is Correct Bro.